# Scala delegate import of implicit conversions

Tags: scala, object, import, delegates, implicit-conversion

In Scala, how can I delegate the importing of implicit conversions into my scope, such that I don't have to have a big "environment" class which provides both library functions/values (for a DSL I am creating) as well as implicit conversions?

In short, can I move my implicit conversions from an object, and still have it imported when I write:

**import MyDslEnvironment._**

?

The goal of this is to make the importing and use of my framework simple and lightweight, in the sense that only a single import statement gives the user the needed functionality of my DSL/framework.

PS: Before anyone flames me - yes, I am aware of pitfalls and nastiness that can come from implicit conversions.

Comment: would it work for you to place them in a package object?

Comment: I point you to this video by Josh Suereth: http://vimeo.com/20308847

Comment: Steve> Please elaborate. I haven't really dabbled in package objects yet :)

Comment: @Felix Package objects are to packages as companion objects are to their companion classes or traits.  Any time you import a package, if there is a package object defined along with it, everything in both the package itself and the associated package object is available.

Comment: This is good. Might be the better abstraction, since, to the user, it will feel like he/she is importing a framework rather than the contents of a singleton object.

Comment: @Steve Feel free to add an answer with your suggestion (and possibly an example of code).
I think you nailed the problem with the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My inclination would be to put the implicits in a package object.

Suppose that your work will be defined in the package com.acme.mydsl. Your source files are arranged in a directory hierarchy com > acme > mydsl. In the directory mydsl, define an object like so:

```
package com.acme; //we are in the mydsl dir, but note no mydsl in
                  //in the package declaration

package object mydsl {

   implicit def idioticallyStringsAre5( s : String ) : Int = 5

   //define other utilities that should be available within
   //the package or importable

}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
scala> import com.acme.mydsl._
import com.acme.mydsl._

scala> def sum( a : Int, b : Int ) = a + b
sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> sum("hello", "there")
res0: Int = 10
```

By importing import com.acme.mydsl._, you got all the package-level function definitions, including the implicit conversion.

I really like package objects. It always seemed hokey in Java to have to make classes full of static members just for utility functions. Package objects serve as very elegant name spaces for these utilities, including implicit conversions.

Comment: Just for good measure. Say I want to create a package filled with tests. If I make a package object and import the dsl-environment from the OTHER package object (eg. the one you show above), will it be globally available in my package, or do I still need to import it in every file that needs it?

Comment: I think that what you suggest wouldn't work -- my intuitions are framed by Java, and maybe that's wrong, but from a Java background, I never expect imports to affect anything other than the present file (or, much more nicely in Scala, the scope that frames the import statement). However, if you want imports available in multiple package objects, you might try Régis Jean-Gilles trick: let the package objects inherit from traits with your implicit definitions. "Package objects can even inherit Scala classes and traits." http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html

Comment: You seem to be correct. Pretty sure it's for the best anyway! One would probably argue to put all the tests in the same file anyway, since you can group multiple objects in a single file, this wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved trivially using traits. Just define your implicit conversions in as many traits as is needed (to achieve modularity), and mix the traits in a single object (MyDslEnvironment). By example:

```
case class Foo( value: Int )
case class Bar( value: String )
object Baz {
  def test( foo: Foo, bar: Bar ) { println( foo + "," + bar ) }
}

trait ImplicitEnv1 {
  implicit def toFoo( value: Int ) = Foo( value )
}

trait ImplicitEnv2 {
  implicit def toBar( value: String ) = Bar( value )
}

object MyDslEnvironment extends ImplicitEnv1 with ImplicitEnv2
```

You can then do:

```
scala> import MyDslEnvironment._
import MyDslEnvironment._
scala> Baz.test( 123, "hello" )
Foo(123),Bar(hello)
```

You could in fact put all your code (`Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` in my above example) inside traits, instead of just your implicit conversion (this may require to use self-type annotations). At which point you will have basically implemented one of the variants of the (in)famous cake pattern.
See http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

Comment: Well. That's quite simple :) I'll see what else people come up with, otherwise I'll accept this.

Comment: Also, note that you can very well turn `MyDslEnvironment` into the package object for your main public package, for convenience. Just replace `object MyDslEnvironment extends ...` into `package object mypackage extends ...`